# gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/project_name/node_modules/node-sass/build'

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu-16.04

I'm deploying an Angular project on Ububtu 16.04 and get these errors when I run sudo npm install. (won't work without sudo). It seems that npm doesn't have permission to install. I recently updated to nodejs to 8.11.4 and still have the same error so it wasn't a version problem apparently. How can I give it the correct permissions?

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/project_name/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1065-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/project_name/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "-libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/front-stormsensor/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
```

Is there something off within my project? Or an incorrect installation? Not sure where to go from here, thank you

Comment: Try running the command with `sudo`. `sudo npm install` for eg/

Comment: Make sure you're logged in as an admin user on the server. Normally www-user or similar. Also check owner of the folder, might need to change it first

Answer (score 72, accepted):

try the following command

```
sudo npm i --unsafe-perm
```

if it doesn't work try the following

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo npm i --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: man I love you! been fighting with this issue for 2 days .. thanks!

Comment: Thanks Man, for saving my day

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it by run this command.

> sudo npm i --unsafe-perm

Answer (score 8):

In case you're installing something globally, you can use:

```
$ sudo npm install -g <package> --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: that is also relevant for macOS users Thanks

Answer (score 8):

use following command to install

`sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

Answer (score 3):

This solution from jnambiar worked for me. 
My OS is OSX 10.11.6. 
It's basically permissions issue.

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo npm i --unsafe-perm
```

Above set of commands helped me resolve the issue.
I am posting this to approve the set of commands which worked for me while I struggled to install the node-sass package for 2 days.

Comment: This was the key to ending several hours of toil.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might still have this problem, I solved it by following the suggestion of the second comment above and logging in as the root user on my ubuntu instance, as described in the second answer on [this question here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root). That allowed me to npm install without errors.

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me on windows.. `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm`

Answer (score 1):

I used `yarn` instead of `npm` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

npm permissions are quite a headache. The above solutions didn't work on my machine. Yarn did the trick.

`sudo npm i yarn -g
yarn add`